# how to alter table multiple column in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE a add (OWNER_NAME VARCHAR2,OWNER_PARENT VARCHAR2);
```

Is it possible to alter table add MULTIPLE columns in a single statement in sqlite3?

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite documentation provides the following picture to illustrate how the ALTER TABLE is understood by SQLite.

[image]

So, it does not seem possible to add multiple columns in a single ALTER TABLE command.

Reference: [SQLite Query Language: ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

**EDIT:**

SQLite is a bit rigid when it comes to modifying existing tables and has limited support for the ALTER TABLE query.

Some more information can be found following this link: [How do I add or delete columns from an existing table in SQLite.](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q11)

The link also provides a workaround to carry out complex table modifications.

In a nutshell (emphasis mine):

> If you want to make more complex changes in the structure of a table, **you will have to recreate the table**. You can save existing data to a temporary table, drop the old table, create the new table, then copy the data back in from the temporary table.